# Why one function compiles successfully, and the second doesn't, when the second only differs with type declaration of inner function?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

```
doublePrepend :: a -> [a] -> [a]
doublePrepend x xs = pair ++ xs
    where pair = [x, x]

doublePrepend2 :: a -> [a] -> [a]
doublePrepend2 x xs = pair ++ xs
    where pair :: [a]
          pair = [x, x]
```

The function `doublePrepend` compiles successfully. The function `doublePrepend2` is the same, but inner helper function `pair` also has additionally type declaration.

Compile error:

```
test.hs:9:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a1’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          pair :: forall a1. [a1]
        at test.hs:8:11-21
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          doublePrepend2 :: forall a. a -> [a] -> [a]
        at test.hs:6:1-33
    • In the expression: x
      In the expression: [x, x]
      In an equation for ‘pair’: pair = [x, x]
    • Relevant bindings include
        pair :: [a1] (bound at test.hs:9:11)
        xs :: [a] (bound at test.hs:7:18)
        x :: a (bound at test.hs:7:16)
        doublePrepend2 :: a -> [a] -> [a] (bound at test.hs:7:1)
  |
9 |           pair = [x, x]
  |
```

But the `x` in the `doublePrepend2` and the `x` in `pair` are the same and their types are the same - `a`, so why haskell cannot match them?

Comment: The `ScopedTypeVariables` solution in the linked duplicate is the way to go. (Admittedly, the error message could be more helpful)

Comment: It's kinda just something you havet to know about the way type signatures work. Without `ScopedTypeVariables`, no two type signatures are in any way connected. Variables in two separate signatures are not the same variable, regardless of name, in exactly the same way that local variables in two different functions have nothing to do with one another, even if they have the same name.